# Package upgraded from ssis2005 to ssis2008r2 not executing from sql agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I upgraded a set of ssis packages from 2005 to 2008r2. the corresponding database has ben upgraded from sql2005 to sql2014. The packages run fine from BIDS. But when i execute them from new sql server agent job ( i have checked the use-32 bit runtime check box)., the package fails with error message as

> Executed as user: ADMIN\SvcSQL13DVMDDEW03. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.6000.34 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:57:06  Error: 2017-07-27 11:57:08.96     Code: 0xC0209302     Source: CBSBankRec50244961Transform Connection manager "TempRBGLINT"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_ERROR.  The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2017-07-27 11:57:08.97     Code: 0x00000008     Source: Check Database Connection      Description: The script returned a failure result.  End Error  Error: 2017-07-27 11:57:24.55     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: CBSBankRec50244961Transform Connection manager "RBGLINT"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ".  End Error  Error: 2017-07-27 11:57:24.57     Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: Log Package 'Started' Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire connection "RBGLINT". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error  Error: 2017-07-27 11:57:40.21     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: CBSBankRec50244961Transform Connection manager "RBGLINT"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ".  End Error  Error: 2017-07-27 11:57:40.22     Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: Log Package 'Failure' Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire connection "RBGLINT". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:57:06  Finished: 11:57:40  Elapsed:  34.102 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

The provider used in the config files for the packages is SQLNCLI10.1 . in the ssis package there is a ole db connection manager - RBGLINT. Just for information - this was automatically upgraded from sql native client \oledb provider to sql native client \ ole db provider 10.0. in the connection manager. I do not see this causing the issue. But just for information.

Any inputs?

Comment: These are the useful parts from that error: `The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered` and `Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server`. Its strange to run a SQL2008R2 package on SQL 2014 - Why not upgrade to SQL 2014?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid has extracted exactly what you'll need to focus on for resolution. His question why not upgrade to ms sql 2014 is a good one, however, if that's not in the cards right now, look at the security context the agent job is running under.

Comment: To determine the context, go to SQL Server Configuration Manager-->Sql Server Services to determine what the services are logged under. Look at the package's connection string "RBGLINT" to see if its a pass-through or a specific user/pwd combo.

Comment: Note that it mentions `SQLNCLI10.1` rather than `SQLNCLI10.0`. This might contribute to the issue. I suggest you generate a connection string on the server using the UDL method to work out which drivers it has installed  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you provided the main error is:

> The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered

From the link below you there is 2 methods for solving this issue:

[The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dbb755af-6997-446c-b3fc-8bacbd8886df/the-requested-ole-db-provider-sqlncli101-is-not-registered?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

1. you need to do is to open the connection manager/connection string and edit it to use Native Client 11.0 which is what comes as default with SSIS 2014
2. Another alternative is to install the Native Client 10.0 from SSIS 2008 installable:

   - https://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/installing-sql-server-native-client-10-0
   - http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2013/04/the-sqlncli10-provider-is-not.html